# need help to move follow camera player in Auto-runner game Unity Platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help to move the following camera for player position in auto runner game. I already try to change the code but it won't work
here the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYkQa.png)

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameSceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerController player;
    public Camera gameCamera;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   

        if (player != null)
        {
            gameCamera.transform.position = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x,gameCamera.transform.position.y,gameCamera.transform.position.z);
            //gameText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Floor(player.transform.position.x);
        }
    }
   // private void Pause()
    //{
        //Time.timeScale = 0f;
   // }  
}```

I already try to add these code



```void Update()
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }``
but still same no change
````

Comment: in what way is it not working?

Comment: It's already working but I want to change player running position to left edge and I confuse

Comment: so you need to calculate the offset

Comment: how? are there some tutorials that could help?

Comment: simple 1st grade maths my friend.. if you want player to be on the left, you need to work out what to add to x to make it so player is on the left not the middle..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this script to your Camera component and attach your player to it :

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x,target.position.y);
    }
}
```